# I keep getting this error : TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))
```

there is an error in the `lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)` where it keep saying that-

**"Parameter 'word' unfilled"**.
The exact error is-

```
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

Comment: Please paste the error as exactly what it gives you. I don't know of any exception off hand that says `unfilled`.

Comment: this is the error that keep showing: TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Answer (score 0):

Suspect value of `word` could be `None` in some case, so you could add this case in the `if` clause:

```py
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word and word not in ignore_letters]
```

Hope it's helpful :)

---

I tried following code, looks above line in your code is correct. But as there is some methods' definitions (`WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize`, `nltk.word_tokenize`) are **unknown**, so maybe you need to check **those definition**.

```py
>>> ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']
>>> words = ['asd']
>>> def f(x):
      pass
>>> words = [f(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
>>> words
[None]
```

If I change `f` to

```py
>>> def f(x, word):
      pass
```

There will be the same error message you met.

Comment: I add more content in my answer, please have a check.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. You just need to add the parenthesis '()' after 'WordNetLemmatizer' to instantiate it correctly.

Should read:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
```